# Using Python sockets on LAN and isolating from WAN

Tags: python, sockets, lan

I have a quick question that I've been wondering about ever since I started socket programming in Python. I'm working on a server/client chat system for sending messages between computers connected to my LAN. My question is: is my LAN completely isolated from the WAN or does it have some kind of connection to it? and if so, how do I isolate my network?

the computers are connected to an all in one router/modem via ethernet cable. Also, the computer which will be running the server has another wireless connection to the internet (connected to the same modem/router but wirelessly)

I hope this makes sense, thanks for reading.

I want all traffic on my LAN to stay private and isolated so only computers in my home network can connect to the server.

Comment: It really depends on the architecture of your network. But usually in home networks, unless you explicitly open a port to the outside world, your internal network is isolated and inaccessible from outside (unless your firewall/router has a security breach or you did something stupid)

Comment: As far as I know, there are no forwarded ports on my router

Comment: There's no way for it to leave your private LAN without forwarding out of your router. Think about deploying a small website using Apache2 server and running it on one of your home machines at 192.168.0.xxx.... Your Apache webserver would serve your site over the intranet... ie: your private network only. Any computers/phones on your private network can access the site at that 192.168.0.xxx address in their browsers

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I finally got that out of my way.